# Getting custom color palette in rasterVis plot3D in R

Tags: raster, r, color

I am trying to insert an RColorBrewer palette to visualize an elevation raster in R using the rasterVis function `plot3D`. The rasterVis reference document shows the following parameters:

```
plot3D(x, maxpixels=100000, zfac=1, drape=NULL, col, rev=FALSE, adjust=TRUE, ...)
```

However, when I use `col=` I get the following error:

```
Error in col(zlen) : 
  a matrix-like object is required as argument to 'row/col'
```

When I use `color=` I get:

```
Error in f(...) : 
  formal argument "color" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

I've also tried this:

```
color.palette = brewer.pal(11, "PRGn")
```

which renders the 3D-plot, but uses the default color palette.

This [article](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rasterVis/docs/plot3D) does not provide a solution.
Nor have I found anything useful on GIS SE or [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979240/r-plotting-a-3d-surface-from-x-y-z/12779434#12779434):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?plot3D`:

> **Arguments**
>
> ...
>
> *col*: A color palette generating **function** such as `rainbow`, `heat.colors`, and `topo.colors`, or one or your own making

You can use `colorRampPalette` to generate your own palette function from given colors, e.g.

```
library("rasterVis")
library("RColorBrewer")
data(volcano)
r <- raster(volcano)
extent(r) <- c(0, 610, 0, 870)
plot3D(r, drape=NULL, zfac=2, col=colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, "PRGn")))
```